# setting max-size-bytes and address-full-policy in HornetQClient

Tags: queue, jms, hornetq

We're using HornetQ core API in order to create ServerLocator from HornetQClient. the ServerLocator is used to create the queues.
here's the code:

```
TransportConfiguration connectorConfig = new TransportConfiguration(InVMConnectorFactory.class.getName());

ServerLocator locator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(connectorConfig);

int ackBatchSize = ConfigWrapperHelper.getIntParameter(ProductMarkingConfigParamEnum.ACK_BATCH_SIZE_FOR_JMS_QUEUES);
locator.setAckBatchSize(ackBatchSize);
locator.setConsumerWindowSize(CONSUMER_WINDOW_SIZE);
locator.setClientFailureCheckPeriod(Long.MAX_VALUE);
locator.setConnectionTTL(-1);

ClientSessionFactory  clientSessionFactory = locator.createSessionFactory(connectorConfig);

ClientSession clientSession = _clientSessionFactory.createSession(XA, AUTO_COMMIT_SENDS, AUTO_COMMIT_ACKS);
clientSession.createQueue(queueName, queueName, IS_DURABLE);
```

the problem is that we need to configure the max-size-bytes and te address-full-policy, for each of the queues.

I know how to do this via the  in the XML, but since I'm using hornetq core in order to configure the queues, these parameters also need to be configured via code.

I saw there's a class called AddressSettings which these parameters can be set in.

my question is - how to configure this AddressSettings object into the ServerLocator?

Or - is there another way to configure these parameters in the ServerLocator which is created from the HornetQCLient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AddressSettings is a server's property, you can't set it from the client's. You can either use it on HornetQServer, or change the equivalent XML.

The AddressSettings is based on wildcards. So you can create an address Settings that will match the name of your queues accordingly to your rules.

If you are working with embedded server, you can use this:

```
server.getAddressSettingsRepository().addMatch("<your-expression-matchin your queue(s)", setting);
```

To configure using the XML, look at this part of the documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html/queue-attributes.html#queue-attributes.address-settings

On JBoss 7 the same XML snippet could be found at standalone-all.xml (or any standalone*.xml that contains hornetq / messaging)

Comment: I understand than since I'm using the HornetQCLient, I can't use the AddressSettings. but currently I'm not using any XML to configure the HornetQClient. how can I add such XML? where should this XML be?